# extern "C" and error C4430

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have got an error when compiling a C++ project under Visual Studio 2008 :

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The line in error is : `extern "C"`
The line in error is the 5th line in the following header file :

```
#ifndef _BY_PORT_H
#define _BY_PORT_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#if ( defined( WIN32 ) || defined(UNDER_CE) )
 #if !defined(WIN)
    #define WIN
 #endif
#endif

//ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
//  Inclusion conditionnelle des headers systŠme
//ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
#ifdef INCL_SYSTEM
#   define INCL_DOS
#   define INCL_WIN
#   define INCL_GPI
#endif

#if ( defined( INCL_DOS ) || defined( INCL_WIN ) || defined( INCL_GPI ) )
#   define SYSTEM_INCLUDED
    //ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
    //  Inclusion minimum dans Windows.h
    //ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
#   define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#   define _INC_OLE_
#   define _OLE2_
#   define _WINCON_
#   define _WINVER_
#   define _WINNETWK_
#   define NORASTEROPS
#   define OEMRESOURCE
#   define NOKERNEL
#   define NOUSER
#   define NOMETAFILE
#   define NOMINMAX
#   define NOMSG
#   define NOOPENFILE
#   define NOSERVICE
#   define NOWH
#   define NOCOMM
#   define NOKANJI
#   define NOHELP
#   define NOPROFILER
#   if !defined(INCL_WIN)
#       define NODEFERWINDOWPOS
#   endif
#   ifdef INCL_WIN
#       undef NOUSER
#       undef NOMSG
#       undef NOOPENFILE
#       undef NOWH
#   endif

#   ifdef INCL_HELP
#       undef NOHELP
#   endif

#   ifdef INCL_GPI
#       undef NOMETAFILE
#       undef NORASTEROPS
#   endif

#   ifdef INCL_DOS
#       undef NOKERNEL
#   endif

#   if (defined(UNDER_CE))
#       undef NOUSER
#   endif

#   if defined(UNDER_CE)
#       define  min(a,b)    ((a)<(b))?(a):(b)
#       define  max(a,b)    ((a)>(b))?(a):(b)
#   endif

#   ifndef STRICT
#       define STRICT
#   endif
#   include <windows.h>

#   if ( defined(UNICODE) && !defined(UNDER_CE) )
#       undef UNICODE
#   endif
#   define ANSI_ONLY
#   include <commctrl.h>

typedef HDC HPS;
typedef HANDLE HAB;

#   ifndef RC_INVOKED
#       if ( defined(INCL_WIN) )
#           include <windowsx.h>
#       endif
#   endif
#else
#   define TRUE                        1
#   define FALSE                       0

    //ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
    //  D‚finition des types de donn‚es portables
    //ÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ
    typedef char                        CHAR;
    typedef char *                      PCHAR;
    typedef unsigned char               UCHAR;
    typedef unsigned char               BYTE;
    typedef short                       SHORT;
    typedef unsigned short              USHORT;
    typedef unsigned short              WORD;
    typedef long                        LONG;
    typedef unsigned long               ULONG;
    typedef unsigned long               DWORD;
    typedef int                         INT;
    typedef unsigned int                UINT;
    typedef void                        VOID;
    typedef char *                      PSZ;
    typedef int                         BOOL;
    typedef void *                      PVOID;
    typedef void *                      HANDLE;
#endif


// -----------------------    Defines communs   ------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifdef NULL
#undef NULL
#endif
#define NULL            0

#define CHSTDSEP        (char)1
#define SZSTDSEP        "\1"

typedef char **         PPSZ;
typedef void **         PPVOID;
typedef long            Coord;

#   define LITTLE_ENDIAN    // I386
#if (defined(BYSTATICLIB) || defined (_LIB))
#   define DLLIMPORT                    extern
#   define DLLEXPORT                    
#else
#   define DLLIMPORT                    __declspec( dllimport )
#   define DLLEXPORT                    __declspec( dllexport )
#endif
#   define _APIFUNC                     __stdcall
#   define _APICFUNC                    __cdecl
#   define _CALLBFUNC                   __stdcall

#if defined(BYSTATICLIB)
#       define BY_LINK      
#else
#       define BY_LINK      DLLIMPORT
#endif

#define MAX_REGKEY_LENGHT 1024

#if defined (UNDER_CE)
#   include <4CE.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif  // _BY_PORT_H
```

I have googled for a while but I have not found why I have got the C4430 error.
Does anyone know why ?

Comment: WTF: 'The line in error is [somewhere] in the following header file'

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yeah there is `#ifdef _cplusplus`

Comment: Please reduce to a SSCCE. Also, why won't you tell us which line has the error? You do want help, right?

Comment: The line in error is the 5th line : extern "C"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your question compiles fine. The problem can be found in the source file that includes it. That file will contain the `#include "..."` statement that includes the head file in the question, at a point where it is not appropriate to write `extern "C"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For what reasons `extern "C"` can be inappropriate ?

Comment: Show the code that includes this header. That's where the error is.

Comment: It is easy to see that I am right simply by trying to compile the code in the Q on its own.

Comment: I have found the source file which depends on the header file. The source file's first line was : `valo// MPS 03/06/27 16:49:52  MICROEDP remplacement getfic par getpath`. The word `valo` caused my error so I have deleted it